# Python & PyQt4: setMenu method not working on a pushButton object

Tags: python, menu, pyqt, pyqt4, qpushbutton

I'm pretty new to PyQt and I'm working on a PyQt4 GUI which has a push button defined as follows:

```
self.buttonFormule11=QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
self.buttonFormule11.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(268, 696, 19, 23))
self.buttonFormule11.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("buttonFormule11"))
self.buttonFormule11.setFlat(True)
```

I would like to set a menu on it, so I've tried to follow the same logic of the other buttons within the same interface (that I didn't program):

```
self.listeWhenDefault = ["Option1", "Option2", "Option3"] 
self.MenuWhenIndicateur = QtGui.QMenu(self.centralwidget)
for option in self.listeWhenDefault:
    checkBox = QtGui.QRadioButton(option,self.MenuWhenIndicateur)
    checkableAction = QtGui.QWidgetAction(self.MenuWhenIndicateur)
    checkableAction.setDefaultWidget(checkBox)
    self.MenuWhenIndicateur.addAction(checkableAction)
    QtCore.QObject.connect(checkBox, QtCore.SIGNAL("toggled(bool)"), self.majWhenFormule) #here it should just modify the text shown into a line edit close to the push button, not relevant

self.buttonFormule11.setMenu(self.MenuWhenIndicateur)
```

However, this procedure doesn't work cause when I click on the pushButton no menu is shown. Can anyone tell me if I'm forgetting something/being wrong anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code you posted (I tested it, and it works for me). So the problems must lie elsewhere in your code.

However, I think the example code uses a somewhat odd approach, and so I have re-written it to use [QActionGroup](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qactiongroup.html) instead.

Here is a simple demo:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Test', self)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        menu = QtGui.QMenu(self.button)
        group = QtGui.QActionGroup(self.button)
        group.setExclusive(True)
        for index in range(1, 4):
            action = group.addAction('Option%d' % index)
            action.setCheckable(True)
            if index == 1:
                action.setChecked(True)
            menu.addAction(action)
        self.button.setMenu(menu)
        group.triggered.connect(self.handleOptionTriggered)

    def handleOptionTriggered(self, action):
        print(action.text())

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(500, 300, 200, 100)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```